# Ways to run an android service automatically

Tags: android, android-service

Besides [scheduling repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and setting an [alarm when the device boots](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) are other ways to run a service once in a while, even the device is asleep.

For example, can the app be notified when network connectivity changes or when there is location (gps and like) changes. Are other ways the app can be woken up?

Just to make it clear, I don't want my app to be running all the time. I want to register it to be triggered from the OS like the `AlarmManager` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android OS sends events for many events occurring in the system, you can handle most of than using a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

You can find the broacast list here: 
https://github.com/ViliusKraujutis/AndroidBroadcastsMonitor/wiki/List-of-all-Broadcast-Intent-actions.-API-17
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html